# UPS Quantum View API Error: Failure: There are no files for the given Request. (330023)

Tags: xml, api, soap, rpc, ups

Before anyone asks, yes, I've asked UPS developers for information on this. They have only provided me with vague answers and upon being on the phone with technical support, it's clear to me that their technical support department doesn't know anything about API's. Also turns out their technical support department is not really allowed to help with this kind of thing...

Their API documentation is also absolutely disastrous and offer little to no help... all I know is that error code 330023 means there are no XML files for the given Request but there should be because I can see incoming and outgoing shipments on Quantum View Manage.

**So I am here with the hopes that someone may know how to make this work.**

I am trying to use their Quantum View API to pull down a list of incoming and outgoing shipments. I have the proper access codes (login, password, and API key)... I won't be posting that information here for obvious reasons.

Here is my request body:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<AccessRequest xml:lang="en-US">
  <AccessLicenseNumber>-- hidden --</AccessLicenseNumber>
  <UserId>-- hidden --</UserId>
  <Password>-- hidden --</Password>
</AccessRequest>
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<QuantumViewRequest xml:lang="en-US">
  <SubscriptionRequest>
    <Name>-- hidden --</Name>
    <DateTimeRange>
      <BeginDateTime>20191217000000</BeginDateTime>
      <EndDateTime>20191223000000</EndDateTime>
    </DateTimeRange>
  </SubscriptionRequest>
  <Request>
    <TransactionReference/>
    <RequestAction>QVEvents</RequestAction>
  </Request>
</QuantumViewRequest>
"https://onlinetools.ups.com/ups.app/xml/QVEvents"
```

It seems the request is hitting the endpoint because I am getting the error:

***Failure: There are no files for the given Request. (330023)***

I am wondering if anyone knows how to fix this. I checked if the incoming and outgoing subscriptions are XML and set to UPS Developer Kit. Both are. But still nothing. UPS is telling me it may take up to 24 hours for the data to appear but I did this 3 days ago and still nothing.

Has anyone here worked with this API and had any success?

Comment: I believe the issue here is that UPS tries to hide files from you, by default, if you have already downloaded them once.  This is pointless since UPS has no way of knowing if the local save was successful on your end. We need some method of saying "all files" instead of "unread files" with the XML request. If you did figure this out please let me know, I'm wallowing in this mess myself right now and the documentation is trash.

Answer (score 3):

I got the same problem, I solved changing the option from CSV to XML in the ups quantum subscription page

Comment: Where even is the ups quantum subscription page?  What a mess. (oh it's here https://www.ups.com/quantum_services/serviceAction?loc=en_US)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue just yesterday.  As a matter of fact I responded to your question yesterday by asking if you'd found an answer yet, but for some reason my response was deleted by an administrator.

Anyway, I decided to create a brand new subscription instead of trying to use an existing one.  It's still a XML subscription available in the UPS Developer Kit - same as the previous one.  For some reason though this did the trick.  I'm no longer receiving the error you're getting.  Try creating a new subscription.

Comment: I found out that UPS Quantum View API does not work with CampusShip accounts. They advised me to work with a UPS.com account linked to the shipper account. And the Quantum View API needs to be activated by UPS. I cannot just create a subscription and use it because it will return nothing.

Comment: @RichardKim
I am confused in the API that what actually the API does.
Does this send notification to the customers of their order or package they ordered or this is another kind of service?